# Parsing JSON Response with Alamofire in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

When using the Alamofire Framework, my responses don't seem to be getting parsed correctly. The JSON response I get has some keys that appear to not be strings, and I don't know how to reference them/get their values.

Here is the part of my code that makes the call:

```
var url = "http://api.sandbox.amadeus.com/v1.2/flights/low-fare-search"
var params = ["origin": "IST", 
         "destination":"BOS", 
      "departure_date":"2014-10-15", 
   "number_of_results": 1, 
              "apikey": KEY]

Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: params)
  .responseJSON { (_, _, json, _) in
    println(json)
  }
}
```

And here is the first section printout when that function is called

```
Optional({
  currency = USD;
  results = ({
      fare = {
        "price_per_adult" = {
          tax = "245.43";
          "total_fare" = "721.43";
        };
        restrictions = {
          "change_penalties" = 1;
          refundable = 0;
        };
        "total_price" = "721.43";
      };
    ...
  });
});
```

You'll notice that `results` is not `"results"`, but `"price_per_adult"` is the correct format. Is there some step I'm missing? When I cast it to NSDictionary it doesn't do anything to help the key format either.

I also tried the same endpoint in javascript and ruby, and both came back without problem, so I'm fairly confident that it is not the API that is causing problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those keys are still `String`s, that's just how `Dictionary`s are `println`d. It looks like it will surround the `String` in quotes when printing it only if it contains non-alphanumeric characters (`_` in this case). You can test this by manually creating a `Dictionary` similar to the one you're getting back from your API request and then printing it:

```
let test = [
    "currency": "USD",
    "results": [
        [
            "fare": [
                "price_per_adult": [
                    "tax": "245.43",
                    "total_fare": "721.43"
                ],
                "restrictions": [
                    "change_penalties": 1,
                    "refundable": 0
                ],
                "total_price": "721.43"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

println(test)
```

Outputs:

```
{
    currency = USD;
    results = (
    {
            fare = {
                "price_per_adult" = {
                    tax = "245.43";
                    "total_fare" = "721.43";
                };
                restrictions = {
                    "change_penalties" = 1;
                    refundable = 0;
                };
                "total_price" = "721.43";
            };
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Confusion over `NSLog` / `println`'s representation not being valid JSON is something I've noticed on many occasions. I wonder how one might go about documenting or clarifying this...

Comment: (Relatedly, I saw someone recently express confusion over the logging output of `NSData`. "Why am I getting numbers when I want text?" is, in fairness, a reasonable question)

Comment: @mattt Yeah, I've seen it quite a bit as well. I think part of the issue is that it's a hard thing to search for on SO; maybe some better question titles would help, but I can't think of a good one offhand. I wonder if putting a note in the related section Alamofire's (and AFNetworking's) README.md regarding this would help? I know that it has nothing to do with those libraries and it would be a little out of place, but it would give the issue some visibility since those libraries are so popular ( nice work BTW ;) ).